# Snapcraft - configure - permission denied

Tags: snap, c++, configure

I'm building a snap but when I build the package, snapcraft tell me :

```
Failed to run './configure --prefix=' for 'synchrorep': Exited with code 126.
```

When I launch ./configure on my local, all is fine.

Here is my snap.yaml file :

```
name: synchrorep
version: "v1.5.5"
summary: Synchronize folders
description: |
  Synchorep is an opensource software to synchronize two directories, that means reporting all modifications of one to the other and vice versa. At the end of synchronization, both directories will be strictly the same. This is useful mainly for nomads who work with a laptop or usb key but may interest also users who want to gain time with the use of differential copy.
base: core18
confinement: classic
parts:
  synchrorep:
    plugin: autotools
    source: https://github.com/sebk69/Synchrorep.git
    build-packages:
      - g++
      - make
      - libgtk2.0-dev
      - libsqlite3-dev
      - libnautilus-extension-dev
apps:
  synchrorep:
    command: "synchrorep --config"
    enter code here
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Where is the directory location please ? If it is inside a read only partition or directory may be. I had a similar experience.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked that project in Github. It is an `make` project not an `autotools` one. So set:

```
...
parts:
  synchrorep:
    plugin: make
...
```

Check use of each plugin in this reference: [Snapcraft - Supported plugins](https://snapcraft.io/docs/supported-plugins)

Comment: Thanks for tip :-)